# How to extract time from mysql time then load to datetimepicker with custom hh:mm:ss

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I have a datetimepicker with custom format `hh:mm:ss tt`

I want to fetch the data from mysql with time data type using `MySqlDataReader`

The date is fine using

```
dtpmyDate.Value = reader.GetDateTime("dateposted").ToShortDateString
```

How about the time?

this one resolve me

```
getTime = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("timeposted")).ToString
Dim today As DateTime = DateTime.Now.Date
Dim timeToSet As New TimeSpan(20, 20, 30)
dtpmyTime.Value = today + " " + getTime
```

dtpmyTime is datetimepicker with custom format is hh:mm:ss
with ShowUpDown = true

I only wants the time value since the date will be updating current date to the database when the record is saved..

Thank you everyone. this site is more practicable place to query my problem that will solve immediately.

Comment: It's not clear what the type of `dtpmyTime` is. If that's the `DateTimePicker`, why are you converting the value to a string at all?

Comment: i want to load the data from mysql time data type to DatetimePicker sir using MySqlDataReader

Comment: Yes, and? `DateTimePicker.Value` is a property of type `DateTime`, so `picker.Value = reader.GetDateTime("timeposted")` should be fine on its own.

Comment: its not working sir. check this link sir http://s21.postimg.org/foqc610o7/Untitled.png

Comment: Right, well the exception speaks for itself. What *is* the value of the date/time for that row and column, in the database?

Comment: the value in mysql with TIME data type is 6:30:24 AM while in DatetimePicker default value is "3/1/2014 11:09 PM" and with a CustomFormat of hh:mm:ss tt

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48771/discussion-between-jane-smith-and-jon-skeet)

Comment: It's not the `DateTimePicker` that's the problem here - it's fetching the value from the database that's causing the issue (look at the stack trace). It *sounds* like a bug in the database driver you're using - we can't tell which one that is from the question, so I suggest you edit the question with more information and look for similar bug reports (and more recent versions).

Comment: ok sir..i let it find out soon..tnx for the help sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assign the .Value of a DateTimePicker, you need to include the date part as well as the time part. If the MySQL column has a type of TIME, then you should read that as a TimeSpan and add it to an appropriate date.

```
Dim today As DateTime = DateTime.Now.Date
Dim timeToSet As New TimeSpan(20, 20, 30)
DateTimePicker1.Value = today + timeToSet
```